# How to calculate a innerWidth of a mobile device with the manufacturer data?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I need to get the innerWidth of the Samsung's Galaxy S10 device in pixels, I've tried googling it - but it didn't help. How can one calculate the device's width based on manufacturer's data? In case you know the width of the Galaxy S10 in px I would appreciate that too.

Answer (score 0):

From time to time, when I really need it I use this table: http://screensiz.es/ you can look for similiar devices if they are new, but may I ask why do you need specific width of a device?

Comment: for a media query

Comment: Usually the best approch isnt to target, specific device, but rather set appropriate breakpointns for instance bootstrap treats everything under 767 asi mobile and it world.